# Leray-Schauder degree in Banach manifolds

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, banach-spaces, banach-manifold

The so called Leray-Schauder degree is usually defined for maps of the form $I - f$, where $f: X \to X$ is a compact map defined on a Banach space. Is there an extended definition for the setting of Banach manifolds?

Comment: The book "Topological analysis" by Martin Väth might have the information you are looking for; see  [Zbl 1248.47001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1248.47001).